# When trying to initiate Shiro SecurityManager from INI resource, encountered java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

Tags: slf4j, log4j2, shiro, apache-commons-logging

I've just started trialling Shiro and was trying the code from [SecurityManager from an INI resource](https://shiro.apache.org/configuration.html#Configuration-SecurityManagerfromanINIresource) when I encountered

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
```

Extended message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtilsBean.<init>(ConvertUtilsBean.java:154)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.<init>(BeanUtilsBean.java:113)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean$1.initialValue(BeanUtilsBean.java:64)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean$1.initialValue(BeanUtilsBean.java:60)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.ContextClassLoaderLocal.get(ContextClassLoaderLocal.java:154)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.getInstance(BeanUtilsBean.java:76)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getInstance(PropertyUtilsBean.java:107)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptor(PropertyUtils.java:498)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.isTypedProperty(ReflectionBuilder.java:409)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.applyProperty(ReflectionBuilder.java:702)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.applySingleProperty(ReflectionBuilder.java:364)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.applyProperty(ReflectionBuilder.java:325)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder$AssignmentStatement.doExecute(ReflectionBuilder.java:955)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder$Statement.execute(ReflectionBuilder.java:887)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder$BeanConfigurationProcessor.execute(ReflectionBuilder.java:765)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.buildObjects(ReflectionBuilder.java:260)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.buildInstances(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:167)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createSecurityManager(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:130)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createSecurityManager(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createInstance(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:94)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createInstance(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniFactorySupport.createInstance(IniFactorySupport.java:123)
    at org.apache.shiro.util.AbstractFactory.getInstance(AbstractFactory.java:47)
    at core.Server.testShiro(Server.java:121)
    at core.Server.main(Server.java:57)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 25 more
```

My code stated by `core.Server.testShiro(Server.java:121)` is:

> org.apache.shiro.mgt.SecurityManager securityManager =
>   factory.getInstance();

My guess is, there is some issue with the shiro.ini file I specified in the previous line of code `Factory<org.apache.shiro.mgt.SecurityManager> factory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:shiro.ini");` and based on the error message, seems that the `beanutils` is the library that needs the `org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory` class

My question is NOT how to correct the shiro.ini, but rather how to solve the ClassNotFoundException.

Note that I am using log4j2 and have already included the log4j2 jars, as well as the slf4j bridging adapters (my understanding is that Shiro need these) jars in my library:

- log4j-api-2.8.2.jar
- log4j-core-2.8.2.jar
- log4j-slf4j-impl-2.8.2.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar

as well as Hibernate jars

I've done some search and saw Les Hazlewood's response to the Shiro User site's question [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory](http://shiro-user.582556.n2.nabble.com/java-lang-NoClassDefFoundError-org-apache-commons-logging-LogFactory-td5135020.html) to look at [explicitly excluding JCL](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#excludingJCL).  The three options stated from the directed site doesn't really apply as I am not using Maven-ized project, just a standalone java project in Netbeans.  However, I've tried including `commons-logging-1.2.jar` and `jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar` in my lib folder (which I gathered is similar to the "provide scope" instruction from the site) but that doesn't solve the exception.

I've also tried including `log4j-jcl-2.8.2.jar` in my lib folder, but the same exception still doesn't go away.

Any help and guidance will much appreciated.  Thanks in advance!  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same error when using shiro-web. Since you already use slf4j then simply add runtime dependency to jcl-over-slf4j. I just did that and it resolved the exception. If you still get the error then you are not doing something right - e.g. placing jars to correct location, ...

Do not include commons-logging together with the jcl bridge. Either use the jcl bridge to slf4j or use the commons-logging both do not make much sense.